# C# Excel VSTO OLE DB Parameters Error must declare scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql, vsto, bind

In Excel writing a VSTO Plugin (using C#) I'm trying to retrieve a value from a SQL database using OLEDB. When I debug this function, it fails on the `catch`.

The message I get is:

> must declare the scalar variable \"@uname\"

But I already did this when I bound the parameter. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public static int getUserID(string username)
    {
        int result = 0;
        string sql = @"select top 1 [ID] FROM " + tbl_users + " WHERE ( [UNAME]=@uname );";
        Console.WriteLine("sql: " + sql);

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", username);

                result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                result = -15;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out... This change works, but I don't really like it.

First I need to use OleDb parameter binding and not SqlParameter binding.

It also seems like OleDb does not like custom naming parameters like `@uname` and instead relies on the order of parameters (I don't like this).
So here's the fix in case anyone was interested:

```
public static int getUserID(string username)
    {
        int result = 0;
        string sql = @"select top 1 [ID] FROM " + tbl_users + " WHERE ( [UNAME]=? );";
        Console.WriteLine("sql: " + sql);
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(username);
                
                
                result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                result = -15;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Yes - that's correct - OleDB does **not** support named parameters - only **positiional** parameters - whether you like that or not - it's just the way it is.